# I keep getting this Error when i tried to use contracts instance to call a contract's function?

Tags: truffle, dapp-development, nodejs

I tried creating instance by:

```
const certificate = Certificate.deployed();
```

OR

```
const certificate = Certificate.at(config.contract_id);
```

ANd i get this Error below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at Provider.sendAsync (/home/manzik/esatya/ecertificate/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:23:36)
at RequestManager.sendAsync (/home/manzik/esatya/ecertificate/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:80:19)
at Object.get [as getNetwork] (/home/manzik/esatya/ecertificate/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:116:33)
at /home/manzik/esatya/ecertificate/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:477:27
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Function.detectNetwork (/home/manzik/esatya/ecertificate/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:468:14)
at Function.deployed (/home/manzik/esatya/ecertificate/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:416:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/manzik/esatya/ecertificate/server/helpers/web3.helper.js:42:33)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at loader (/home/manzik/esatya/ecertificate/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5) }
```

Comment: You're not calling any contract function in the code that you've posted here! The error `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` is given on a piece of code which you haven't bothered to post here, and this is not a guessing challenge, so please edit your question!

Comment: What is config contract_id ? Are u using ganache? Which web3js version?